# Ajax AutoCompleteExtender - Why is this code not working?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, ajax

Using aspnet 3.5. Here is my code. Yes I know I should be using jquery.

Nothing happens when I type into the textbox. I have a breakpoint in the webservice which is not getting hit.

What am I doing wrong?

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="tbName" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server"
  TargetControlID="tbName"  
    ServiceMethod="GetList" ServicePath="wsWebServices.asmx" 
    MinimumPrefixLength="2">
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public string[] GetList(string prefix, int count)
{
     return new string[] { "abc", "def", "hij", "abc", "def", "hij", "abc", "def", "hij", "abc", "def", "hij" };
}
```

Comment: Have you checked my answer regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried calling the webservice from a javascript function and that worked. So the problem is somehow that the autocomplete is not picking up the "result" of the webservice.

All the other answers on this page either weren't applicable or didn't work.

I think something is missing in the ajax documentation. If I ever get this working I will write it up here.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the references from WebMethod and ScriptMethod to the fully qualified names:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
```

In your parameter change prefix to prefixText  (The return type and parameter name and type must exactly match, including case)

```
public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
```

Ensure your Script Manager is on your page.

Comment: Fully qualifies names did not help. I am not sure why you are saying to use prefixText instead of prefix. I am coding in C#.

Comment: @TheMoot That's what it states directly from the ASP.NET website.  "Note that you can replace "GetCompletionList" with a name of your choice, but the return type and parameter name and type must exactly match, including case." - http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

Comment: @TheMoot I would try prefixText as stated on the ASP.NET Website.

Comment: Is the cc1 registered correctly to the ajaxtoolkit.dll? And do you have a script manager on that page? Do any other ajax controls work on that page at all?

Comment: I tried calling the webservice from a javascript function that I put on the page and that worked. So the problem is somehow that the autocomplete is not wired up to and running the webservice.

Comment: prefixText made 100% difference  PLUS Webmethod should always be static

Answer (score 0):

```
define your web method as static like
public static string[] GetList(string prefix, int count)
```

Comment: Didn't make a difference. Besides, one I get the plumbing hooked up, I am going to do a database call so I couldn't use static anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

ASPX

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbName" runat="server"  autocomplete="off"  ></asp:TextBox>

<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="tbName"  
    ServiceMethod="GetList" 
    ServicePath="wsWebServices.asmx" 
    MinimumPrefixLength="2">
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

in the service 
Check Your asmx Path too
Above the Class Put the 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class wsWebServices: System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

```
  [WebMethod]
  public string[] GetList(string prefix, int count)
  {


return new string[] { "abc", "def", "hij", "abc", "def", "hij", "abc", "def", "hij", "abc", "def", "hij" };
  }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry. I do not understand what you are saying here. Your aspx is the same as mine. How is your webservice different?